# how give image path for html coding in android

Tags: android, html, background

i developing an application, in that i configure html data . But the  background image for data is not effected means the image path is not getting.

i placed my image :res/drawable-hdpi folder.

and i am using the following logic:

```
strBody += "<tr><td background='../res/drawable-hdpi/msgblue_box.png' style='word-break:break-all;width:50%;'>" +   dslist.get(i).getBody()+"<br>"+ dslist.get(i).getDateformat()+ "</td><td style='width:50%'></td></tr>";
```

So, please guide me how solve this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to  use the getResources.getDrawable to get image in your code

```
ImageView img=new ImageView(this);    
 Drawable im= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name); 
  img.setImageDrawable(im);


strBody += "<tr><td background="+img+ "style='word-break:break-all;width:50%;'>" +   dslist.get(i).getBody()+"<br>"+ dslist.get(i).getDateformat()+ "</td><td style='width:50%'></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but it is also not effected.